# Best practice to match the 2nd level (nested) resource index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

(I am doing the exercise of online course from codeschool, the rails app from scratch part 1)

Here is my `routes.rb`

```
resources :destinations, only: :index 

resources :trips do
  resources :destinations
end
```

and the `rake routes` result has these two routes go to the same action:

```
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
     destinations GET    /destinations(.:format)                 destinations#index
trip_destinations GET    /trips/:trip_id/destinations(.:format)  destinations#index
```

I wish to match the `trip_destinations` to `trip#show`, i.e. redirect to `/trips/:id`, I have some solutions like hard code it in `routes.rb` or add redirection in `destination#index`. Which one is better? Is there a best practice to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :trips do
  resources :destinations do
    member do
      get 'index' => 'trips#show'
    end
  end
end
```

This will work for you, but it's based on faulty design because the response does not match the request. In other words, it's a bad route. A trip's destination index resource should respond with a trip's destination index, not the trip object itself.

The `/trips/:id/destinations` path should not be redirecting or rendering `/trips/:id`. There shouldn't be a link pointing to `trips/:id/destinations` in the first place, unless your application can respond with the appropriate resource.

It's very easy to get carried away with fancy routes and URL presentation. Be sure your routes make sense. It will save you loads of trouble in the future.

Comment: Thanks @gg_s.  You are right, I should explicitly disable that route.